# Integrate CSS Stylesheets that were made for HTML for Scene Builder

Tags: java, css, javafx, scenebuilder

i have found some cool CSS Sheets for some HTML websites and wanted to use them for my own JavaFX project.

CSS :

```
.container {
  zoom: 1;
}

.container:before, .container:after {
  content: '';
  display: table;
}

.container:after {
  clear: both;
}

.column {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
  padding: 30px 0;
  text-align: center;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.column .button + .button {
  margin-left: 20px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
  .column {
    width: 50%;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 400px) {
  .column {
    width: 100%;
  }
}

.button {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  height: 33px;
  line-height: 33px;
  padding: 0 15px;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-shadow: 0 -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  border: 2px solid;
  border-radius: 7px;
  outline: 0;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  box-shadow: 0 2px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
}

.button:before, .button:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
}

.button:before {
  top: -5px;
  bottom: -5px;
  left: -5px;
  right: -5px;
  z-index: -1;
  border-radius: 9px;
}

.button:after {
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  border: 2px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
  border-bottom: 0;
  border-radius: 7px;
}

.button.alt {
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
}

.button.alt:before {
  display: none;
}
```

But I encountered some problems.

First if I select the file for the Anchor Pane it shows a little yellow sign and an error.For the style class I just can choose between container and column.

Even if I delete the .container and the . column code in the Css and add the css sheet to the button I get the message of:

```
Jan. 24, 2018 2:22:04 VORM. javafx.css.CssParser declaration
WARNING: CSS Error parsing file:/C:/Users/AllinOne/IdeaProjects/MeineApp/out/production/MeineApp/sample/Button.css: Unexpected function '-webkit-linear-gradient(' while parsing 'background-image' at [4,22]
Jan. 24, 2018 2:22:04 VORM. javafx.css.CssParser declaration
WARNING: CSS Error parsing file:/C:/Users/AllinOne/IdeaProjects/MeineApp/out/production/MeineApp/sample/Button.css: Unexpected function '-moz-linear-gradient(' while parsing 'background-image' at [5,22]
Jan. 24, 2018 2:22:04 VORM. javafx.css.CssParser declaration
WARNING: CSS Error parsing file:/C:/Users/AllinOne/IdeaProjects/MeineApp/out/production/MeineApp/sample/Button.css: Unexpected function '-o-linear-gradient(' while parsing 'background-image' at [6,22]
```

Is there anyone that can explain me how I set this up for my JavaFX App?

I have read there are some differences between CSS for HTML and Java FX.
Is there maybe a source for free CSS for buttons for java fx? I couldnt find one only for HTML most of the time.

Comment: "Is there maybe a source for free CSS for buttons for java fx" is really off-topic for this forum: this is a Q&A forum for programming questions (i.e. for writing your own code): asking for recommendations for libraries or tools is explicitly [off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: [Here](http://fxexperience.com/2011/12/styling-fx-buttons-with-css/) is a `StyleSheet` you can use for `JavaFx` `Buttons`. I have also used these ideas to style other `Nodes` like the `ListView` cell.

Answer (score 2):

JavaFX uses CSS (the *language*) to define styles for UI nodes. The *set of properties* of JavaFX nodes that you can set with CSS are more or less completely distinct from the set of properties that you can set for HTML elements.

(In particular, CSS in JavaFX is used almost solely to *style* the controls; it is not used for layout, as it can be in HTML. However, even when used for style, the property names are deliberately different.)

Consequently, there's no real way to take a CSS file written for HTML and apply it to a JavaFX scene graph. Just because the syntax is the same, does not mean it can be used in a different context.

See the [reference guide for JavaFX CSS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html) for a full list of CSS properties for each JavaFX node type. You can convert some of the properties for the [button](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#button), for example, to JavaFX CSS properties.